# Banging noise Over bumps

Tags: suspension, car

I get banging noise over bumps. Its seems like car has been dropped from some height. If I go slowly over bumps then nothing comes and even suspension works perfectly fine but this noise comes when I driving little fast. Even I can feel the small hairline as well.

For this issue I have replaced sway bar bushings, new engine mounts left and right other two are good. Other control arm bushing also checked and looks fine. Then strut mounts replaced, then shock absorber also replaced. Even endlinks, ball joints are also checked. But still sound comes. it sounds like gut gut...  over bumps...
I dont know if I need to replace springs something else. I dont know. Please let me know what all can I check..

Its Nissan Teana 230JM 2007... 80k kms driven.

Comment: A loud bang might be the ball joint if your car has it. If it's most or less continually small sound it might be the link kit